# Examples of the axes of the lambda cube

Tags: lambda-calculus

The Wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_cube is difficult to assimilate. I think examples (code snippets) that demonstrate each refinement might help clarify. For instance, a generic List in C# would demonstrate types based on types (I think). What are examples of the other axes? Are there meaningful yet succinct examples of combinations of multiple refinements, say the whole "calculus of constructions" in one snippet?

Comment: Is [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19053/does-types-being-terms-imply-your-dependend-theory-is-considered-polymorphic/19054#19054) what you're looking for? [This](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/49189/what-terms-type-systems-exclude/49381#49381) may also be of interest.

Comment: I'll add [my own](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36054/how-do-you-get-the-calculus-of-constructions-from-the-other-points-in-the-lambda/36058#36058) attempt to answer this question.